# Searching in php array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
$members = array(
'Group1' => array(
    'user1',
    'user2'
),
'Group2' => array(
    'user3',
    'user4'
),
'Group3' => array(
    'user5'
));
```

How can I search group name for specific user ?

Comment: yes you can, what did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest (logic wise) way is a quick foreach loop with an `in_array()` check to find whether or not your name is in the sub array:

```
$search = 'user4';

foreach($members as $group_name => $names)
  if(in_array($search, $names))
    echo $search . ' is in ' . $group_name; // user4 is in Group2
```

Example: https://eval.in/148332

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a user may occur in multiple groups:

```
$groups = array();
foreach ($members as $group_name => $group_members) {
    if (in_array('user4', $group_members)) {
        $groups[] = $group_name;
    }
}
```

The variable `$groups` will contain all the group names that matched, though in the above example that's only "Group2".